# Places Google api autocomplete -> not showing numbers within the street

Tags: html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

So I've the places google api on my site, and I'm struggling with the autocomplete.

As we see below, I can enter the address with the street number and it's perfectly recognised and suggested by the autocomplete

[image]

But if I enter the business directly, it's not suggesting me the street number, but the business name + street + city + country

[image]

We manage an events website, where people enter the events info with the address and the problem is that the address doesn't look complete, so the people get always confused about the street number

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
  <input type="hidden" id="place_id" name="place_id">
</div>
```

[Fiddle to reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/tronne/ahj3y98k/4/)

Comment: Can you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can look at?

Comment: fiddle added, thank for your interest! :)